# Sublime text 3 anaconda not working

Tags: python, bash, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I've installed [Anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda) via package control. It's installed but none of the functionality is working (i.e. I can't do `command-shift-r` to find a class). I'm guessing I need to add something to my bash profile? When I do `which python` I get the following path `/usr/bin/python`

I tried adding `PATH="/usr/bin/python/bin:$PATH"` to my `.bash_profile`. How can I get anaconda to work properly with sublime?

Comment: Is they command properly configured in sublime settings? Often a package demonstrates use of a command that is not actually configured, you have to do it yourself

Comment: good question, it seems like this is the issue